# Mockito Mock when field changes

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

I have a class like

```
class A{

Map<String, String> obj;
B b;

public void method1(str1, str2, str3){
  obj = (new map dependent on str1 and str2)
  String str = b.method2(obj, str3)
  return str;
}
```

How can I mock **b.method2**. What I mean is I want to test method1 and check that correct String is returned. For that purpose I want to do `when(b.method2()).thenReturn("myStr").`

Comment: How is `b` initialized? And more importantly - what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: b is wired in. And I want to test method1. So I need to mock method2, but how can I refer obj in when

Comment: You can't. Use `any(Map.class)` when stubbing or use an `ArgumentCaptor`.

Comment: Well, the whole point of the test is probably to check that `b.method2()` has been called with a specific map. So you shouldn't stub `b.method2()`. Instead, you should  `verify(b).method2(theExpectedMap)`.

Comment: @JBNizet I updated the question. the method from b depends on argument passed and the map which is created. So how should my when be?

Comment: You say _depends_, but you're stubbing the method.

Comment: Then stub the method with any() and eq(str3), and then verify that method2 has been called with the right map. Or stub it with the expected map and str3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a complete, working example:

```
public class B {
    public String method2(Map<String, String> obj, String str3) {
        // this is irrelevant for our test of A
        return null;
    }
}

public class A {

    private Map<String, String> obj;
    private B b;

    public A(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    /**
     * Replaces the internal obj map to a new Map containing str1 as key and str2 as value,
     * and calls b.method2() with that map and str3.
     * @return the value returned by b.method2()
     */
    public String method1(String str1, String str2, String str3) {
        obj = new HashMap<>();
        obj.put(str1, str2);
        String str = b.method2(obj, str3);
        return str;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getObj() {
        return obj;
    }
}

public class ATest {
    @Test
    public void method1ShouldCallMethod2WithCreatedMap() {
        B mockB = mock(B.class);

        Map<String, String> expectedMap = new HashMap<>();
        expectedMap.put("hello", "world");

        when(mockB.method2(expectedMap, "!")).thenReturn("ok");
        A a = new A(mockB);
        String result = a.method1("hello", "world", "!");
        assertEquals("ok", result);
        assertEquals(expectedMap, a.getObj());
    }

    // Same test, other technique
    @Test
    public void method1ShouldCallMethod2WithCreatedMap2() {
        B mockB = mock(B.class);


        when(mockB.method2(Mockito.<Map<String, String>>any(), anyString())).thenReturn("ok");
        A a = new A(mockB);
        String result = a.method1("hello", "world", "!");
        assertEquals("ok", result);

        Map<String, String> expectedMap = new HashMap<>();
        expectedMap.put("hello", "world");

        assertEquals(expectedMap, a.getObj());
        verify(mockB).method2(expectedMap, "!");
    }
}
```

Comment: How will this work? Because we are creating new map "expectedMap", but the object returned within mehtod1 wouldn't be equal to this expectedMap, so how will mocking work?

Comment: Thanks, it works but I am not sure as to why. The thing I am finding it difficult to understand is if we are creating a new map and using it in when, then why the method is getting mocked, because during runtime this expected map won't be equal to the created map in the method?

Comment: Yes, it will be. two maps are equal if they contains equal key/value pairs.